# VBA Finding name header and sum values

Tags: excel, vba

The code at this point goes without error, but it does not add up the NOMINAL_MAX value and it does not give the value in the indicated place. What's wrong with this code?

```
Dim rTable As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim rCriteria As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim NOMINAL_MAX as String 
    With wbMe.Sheets("pochodne")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=NOMINAL_MAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
            SumCriteria = wbMe.Sheets("pochodne").Range("X35").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rTable.Columns(1), NOMINAL_MAX, rTable.Columns(rCol.Column))
        Else
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: We can't run this code in its current form because it's missing some info.  For example, what is the variable `Criteria`?  And shouldn't the variable `NOMINAL_MAX` be a string when you use the `.Find` method?  Please make some edits so that others can run this code.

Comment: The code is still not runnable.  Try this: step through your code (use the F8 key) and watch your data as your code goes line by line.  Once you reach the line that causes your headers to collapse, let us know.

Comment: I run this code normally, but it does not add up the values from the NOMINAL_MAX column to me now and does not give the result in X35. I tond have any error and now i dont have any collapse now . Just need sum of return Nominal_MAX name

Comment: Right, and that's what we expect.  The `SumIf` function is used to add values when a condition is met.  That condition is checked against every member of the `Range`.  In your case, you want to add up all the members of a column.  I understand why you believe that the `SumIf` function should work here, but it won't.  The logic of your code is OK too.  Find the desired column, and sum all of its members.  You just can't use the `SumIf` function for that.

Comment: So what i should i do it?

Comment: Come up with a solution that does not use the `SumIf` function, because you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240988/discussion-between-koniecswiata-and-tehdrunksailor).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `SumIf` function outside of its intended use, which is why you're not getting results.  See Microsoft's documentation (and examples) of the function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

I do not know why your headers are collapsing, but I can see that you reference your data as a `Range` instead of a `ListObject` despite calling the variable `rTable`.  A `ListObject` is the VBA datatype that Tables use in Excel.  If you convert your data to a table in Excel, you can add a "total" row to the bottom of the table, and then reference the total of the column that you want in your code.

I recommend taking some time to familiarize yourself with how to work with tables (`ListObject`) in Excel.

Comment: this is not the answer i expect, sumif i know but i have a problem with the code i presented. If you know how to help, please provide your code suggestion or modified code.